# Why did grub load show up on multiple machines?

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2

I may have seen something like this before but not recently for sure.  I have 2 machines running on Ubuntu 14.04.  The machines are not the same.  1 is a laptop and 1 is a desktop.  One of the machines has nothing installed except the defaults.  Today not 1 machine but both machines showed something like this ( I did not have a camera but this is what it looked like below ) and I selected the *Ubuntu option for both.

[image: grub load]

What could cause both machines to do this?  Is there any possible security risks why it may have shown up for both? ( like tampering or rootkits )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is nothing to Panic about!** , this is just the GRUB .

Somehow you have set GRUB timeout to a non-zero value on both of your machines.

To disable this Screen, follow these steps :

- Open a terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>
- `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- You will see a command-line text editor. In that file, Search for `GRUB_TIMEOUT=`
  & Set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` . This will make the GRUB screen stay for 0 seconds (i.e, It wont show up ) .
- Now press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Y</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Saving Changes)
- Now in your terminal, `sudo update-grub` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now you wont See Grub :)